# iOS Cache Directory size limit

Tags: ios, iphone, nsfilemanager

I will download some files into NSCacheDirectory on iOS (Application_Home/Library/Caches).
What is the maximum size of file that can save NSCacheDirectory?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How much space is left on the device?

Comment: If enough space on iPhone, It doesn't matter what size of file?

Comment: Exactly. The only limit is the available space.